# ImportError on subpackage when running setup.py test

Tags: python, setuptools, distutils

I'm trying to create an install package for a Python project with included unit tests. My project layout is as follows:

```
setup.py
src/
    disttest/
        __init__.py
        core.py
tests/
    disttest/
        __init__.py
        testcore.py
```

My `setup.py` looks like this:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import setuptools

setup(name='disttest',
      version='0.1',
      package_dir={'': 'src'},
      packages=setuptools.find_packages('src'),
      test_suite='nose.collector',
      tests_require=['Nose'],
      )
```

The file `tests/disttest/testcore.py` contains the line `from disttest.core import DistTestCore`.

Running `setup.py test` now gives an `ImportError: No module named core`.

After a `setup.py install`, `python -c "from disttest.core import DistTestCore"` works fine. It also works if I put `import core` into `src/disttest/__init__.py`, but I don't really want to maintain that and it only seems necessary for the tests.

Why is that? And what is the correct way to fix it?

Comment: I'm wondering: is it maybe common practice to do a `setup.py install` before `setup.py test`? The [setuptools documentation](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools#test) sounds like this isn't the case, my sources should be put on `sys.path` automatically. Maybe `nose.collector` is not made aware of my `package_dir` base directory?

Comment: How are You importing core in testcore.py? What exactly is in your sys.path/PYTHONPATH?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to double-check this, but it looks like your tests are importing the `disttest` package in the `tests/` directory, instead of the package-under-test from the `src/` directory.

Why do you need to use a package with the same name as the package-under-test? I'd simply move the testcore module up to the tests directory, or rename the `tests/disttest` package and avoid the potential naming conflict altogether.

In any case, you want to insert a `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` line just before the failing import and play around with different import statements to see what is being imported from where (`import sys; sys.modules['modulename'].__file__` is your friend) so you get a better insight into what is going wrong.

Comment: I think your assumption is absolutely correct. The way `setup.py test` launches my tests, it probably puts `tests/disttest/` in front of `src/disttest/` in `sys.path` and Python never 'merges' packages with the same name together. Just renaming `tests/disttest/` to `tests/disttest2` (only for testing purposes, obviously) fixes the issue. I'll have to check how other projects do this and what the best practices are here, as having all testing modules in the same directory is not an option for huge projects, of course. Thanks for the debugging tips!

Comment: I'm at a loss why `src/disttest/__init__.py` is executed before `tests/disttest/__init__.py`, though. (I confirmed that by adding print statements to them.) I would have expected it to be the other way around (or possibly `src/disttest/__init__.py` not being executed at all, because all imports just import `tests/disttest/`), but that was just out of curiousity and I can solve my problem now.